# Windows universal app ivalueconverter reference error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, ivalueconverter

I had an application for windows store, after a while the application is been converted to universal. I have some converters but now they don't work.

All the views and the code from the portable class project was moved to the universal project.

Anyone know how the converters can work with this scenario?

In the image the first error is related

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Class with IValueConverter

[image]

Comment: Could you show the XAML and project stucture?

Comment: In which namespace is the stringformatconveter located? It is possible that it changed during the conversion to a universal app

Comment: I removed the common reference and added again in the xaml but the errors keep appearing.

The current namespace is eMobilePOS.WP.Common